# Catalog Search index process error during indexation process: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: category, products, reindex, magento2.4.6, opensearch

I installed Magento 2.4.6-p3 by 1-click installation under Hostmonster webhosting c-panel. I didn't touch any thing. It went through well and gave me Admin Access of Magento 2.4.6-p3.

I searched whole last week to fix 'product not showing issue', and read about reindex via SSH. So, I ran it found the following error while reindex. I ran it under my webhosting Hostmonster SSH.

[image]

catalog search index process error during indexation process:
could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster

Could you help me how to fix this issue under my webhosting at Hostmonster environment? Should I put some kinds of SSH command to fix? Or, change some value under Magento Back End Admin?

'No alive nodes found in your cluster' kept showing while I click 'Test Connection' under Admin - Configuration - Catalog. Could you help me how to fix this issue and use Magento 2.4.6-p3 properly under Hostmonster webhosting environment?

[image]

How can I check if the opensearch is working? As I see Store - Configuration - Catalog, the opensearch was set as default. As I test connection, No alive nodes found in your cluster just as I posted the error image. After 1-click installation under c-panel on Hostmonster, I haven't touch any thing. Every thing should be set as default mode.

Is there any way to start the opensearch if it was turn off as a default mode? How can I turn it on?

Many many thanks.
Best,
CMYK337

Comment: Please restart your Elasticsearch service and ensure that you are using the correct host.

Answer (score 0):

1st Start -------> elasticsearch

2nd Start--------> Xampp or wamp

Then Go to Magento root Directory ---> Run CMD Command

Paste and Enter Following Command

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

--------After Finish------

Then Paste and Enter Following Command

php bin/magento cache:flush

its woking..

Please try this. let me know this is working or not. if my solution is working then accept my answer and give an upvote.

thanks